# How to run a node.js server on Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure

I've followed this tutorial ([https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/create-a-website-(mac)/](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/create-a-website-%28mac%29/)) to the letter but I'm not getting the response I expect from my node server.

It works when I run node locally but once deployed to Azure I get this error:

> iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.
>
> HRESULT: 0xb HTTP status: 500 HTTP reason: Internal Server Error

This is my server.js:

```
var http = require( "http" );

http.createServer(function ( req, res ) {
    res.writeHead( { "Content-Type": "text/plain"} );
    res.end( "Hello Azure!\n" );
} ).listen( process.env.port );
```

Comment: Scott Hanselman's article on Azure might be of some help: 

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WindowsAzureNoKidding.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tried the exact same steps myself of the tutorial and was able to get the `Hello world` message. This is my deployment at the moment: http://nodetestordinacc.azurewebsites.net/ (Note, I'll likely remove it in the future).

If it all runs locally then you should be able to follow the steps like I did from the tutorial and get it running successfully.

Can you verify the steps:

- git init (I used the Github shell)
- git add .
- git commit -m "initial commit"
- git remote add azure [URL for remote repository]
- git push azure master

The *[URL for remote repository]* must be replaced with the url the portal provided in the beginning of the tutorial:

[image: Git URL provided by the portal]

**Update:**

This is the code I used. Please copy it over exactly:

```
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.port || 1337;
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(port);
```

Comment: I can verify those steps. The website is online through git and I've made several changes while trying to solve the issue. Maybe I'll just delete the whole thing and try again.

Comment: No. Now instead of just an empty response I'm receiving a server error. I've updated the question.

Comment: I copied in my code that I used to have it working. Please try that as well, run it locally and test it there and then take the same steps like I did (as explained in the tutorial). Perhaps also throw away your website instance and create a new one just to be sure.

Comment: Yes. Copying your code works. Though I really wonder why my code didn't. Giving you the answer though for helping me out. Thanks.

Comment: Just going over it again. It seems you didn't put in the step for the `var port = process.env.port || 1337;`. I tried your code but didn't get it to work on my laptop. Even when I added the extra || in the listen part then it worked locally but not after a new deployment.

Comment: I didn't add that variable at first because it felt redundant. It's weird that that would be a code breaking change. Thanks for trying it out and confirming!

Comment: I had the exact problem and couldnt figure out what it was. The deploy went fine and the server started up as it should (according to the nodejs-output). But I couldnt reach the site - until I did this: process.env.port || 1337. Apparently settings a customized port doesnt work, atleast not for me.