# Node.js + Express only work on port 3000 on test server

Tags: node.js, azure, express

On Local Test it work. on different port (3001, 8080)

But on Test Server (Azure)

I run 2 instance of Node App on same machine

```
$ node api1/index.js (on port 3000)
$ node api2/index.js (on port 3001)
```

and

```
$ node api1/index.js (on port 3001)
$ node api2/index.js (on port 3000)
```

But it only works on port 3000.

How do I set different port in Express?

Now, I've changed at app.listen(3001) on index.js and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Often cloud platforms set an environment variable that contains the port they want you to stick your app on. I don't have any experience with Azure... See the answer here: [How to run a node.js server on Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435630/how-to-run-a-node-js-server-on-azure)

Specifically:

```
var port = process.env.port
```

Most cloud providers in my experience don't let you play on other ports. You can always specify a localhost port too, though by doing this:

```
var port = process.env.port || 3001 //(or whatever)

app.listen(port);
```

this way if process.env.port is undefined (which it will be in your dev environment) you fallback to 3001.

Make sense?

Comment: Frack.  Glad I know this now!